# How to combine/merge cells of a column into a list with a common user id in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

### Example of what I'm trying to achieve

I want to merge/combine all group names that a user is a member of into a list of group names for each user record.

For example, lets say I have the following users in my database:

```
___________________
user_id | group_name
1         'admin'
1         'operator'
2         'user'
2         'operator'
3         'user'
```

Now I want to fetch them and get the following result:

```
____________________
id       | group_name
1         ['admin', 'operator']
2         ['user', 'operator']
3         ['user']
```

### Actual case / what I'm working on now

I have the following query to query users and the groups they belong to:

```
SELECT
    tb1.auth_userid,
    tb1.extendeduserinformationid,
    tb2.date_joined,
    tb2.last_login,
    tb2.username,
    ag.name AS group_name,
    CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS name,
    tb1.email,
    department,
    rfid,
    array_agg(ag.name) as x
FROM
    myappdb.extendeduserinformation tb1
JOIN myappdjango.auth_user tb2 ON tb1.auth_userid = tb2.id
JOIN myappdjango.auth_user_groups aug ON tb2.id = aug.user_id
JOIN myappdjango.auth_group ag ON ag.id = aug.group_id
WHERE
    tb1.active = 1
GROUP BY
    tb1.extendeduserinformationid,
    tb1.auth_userid,
    tb2.date_joined,
    tb2.last_login,
    tb2.username,
    ag.name,
    tb1.firstname,
    tb1.lastname,
    tb1.email,
    tb1.department,
    tb1.rfid
ORDER BY
    username
```

Here is a part of the result that query gives:

```
auth_userid | x
"10" ...    "{administrators}"
"11" ...    "{administrators}"
"11" ...    "{controllers}"
```

As you see, the user with id 11, isn't merged into one row with the group names in a list as I want.

I want:

```
auth_userid | x
"10" ...    "{administrators}"
"11" ...    "{administrators, controllers}"
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: `ag.name AS group_name` vs. `array_agg(ag.name) as x `? Remove the first one, and also remove ag.name from the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to group by ag.name since it would be the aggregation for the group :

```
SELECT
    tb1.auth_userid,
    tb1.extendeduserinformationid,
    tb2.date_joined,
    tb2.last_login,
    tb2.username,
    CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS name,
    tb1.email,
    department,
    rfid,
    array_agg(ag.name) as group_name
FROM
    mbraindb.extendeduserinformation tb1
JOIN mbraindjango.auth_user tb2 ON tb1.auth_userid = tb2.id
JOIN mbraindjango.auth_user_groups aug ON tb2.id = aug.user_id
JOIN mbraindjango.auth_group ag ON ag.id = aug.group_id
WHERE tb1.active = 1
GROUP BY
    tb1.extendeduserinformationid,
    tb1.auth_userid,
    tb2.date_joined,
    tb2.last_login,
    tb2.username,   
    tb1.firstname,
    tb1.lastname,
    tb1.email,
    tb1.department,
    tb1.rfid
ORDER BY username
```

Comment: This worked great. Just remove it from the GROUP BY as the answer suggests. Thanks!